# Xamarin listview transport

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am creatin basic mobile app. And I have a add button and I have a listview.
I can show the values ​​I added in the listview, but what I want is to show the listiview on another page, thank you in advance for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/945ZC.png)

When I put x:name in NewItemPage.xaml, it's okay, but I want to show listview in ItemPage.xaml.

Comment: You could define a custom ContentView and create a listview in it . In such a way you can put the ContentView in any ContentPage .

Comment: I am still confused, so you have one page with an add button, and a list view; and what you want to do is show the listview that is on the page with the button in a new page right?

Comment: Show some code please. We should not need to guess

Comment: ListView is a basic control in Xamarin. We need to set up its items source to make it visible on the screen. So we only need to store the source. When you want to display the items, retrieve them from your local storage and then use a list view to present them on the page.